# Vaadin website with spring boot does not start on the server

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I developed a vaadin website including spring boot. The generated jar file can be started locally.
If I want to start this on a windows server, the following exception occurs:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Aug 29 12:05:00 CEST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webpack exited prematurely
com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webpack exited prematurely
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1617)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1580)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:299)
at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:109)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webpack exited prematurely
at com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.doStartDevModeServer(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:218)
at com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.runOnFutureComplete(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:170)
at com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.lambda$new$0(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:161)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)

Project-Info:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>22.0.21</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Standard
```

Unfortunately I can not find the error.

Comment: Please build your application in production mode and see if the error stays the same.

Comment: I think I start the application in production mode because I found this tag in the pom.xml:  <productionMode>true</productionMode>

Comment: And this in the application proberties: vaadin.servlet.productionMode=true

Comment: Please do what @Knoobie suggested: https://vaadin.com/docs/v22/flow/production/production-build

Comment: now I have the following exception: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to load content of 'C:\Vaadin\Workspace\online-statisitikcenter\frontend\index.html'.

Comment: Did you build the application with mvn package -Pproduction